# KeyDown and KeyPress only firing once when key remains pressed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to perform the same task multiple times on either the KeyPress or KeyDown events in a Windows Forms application.

```
    private void canvas_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test passedy");
    }
```

But the event only fires once. The same thing happens with the KeyPress event.

If I remember correctly, in previous applications, the event just kept firing for as long as the user had their finger pressing the key.

How can I ensure that this event keeps firing?

I tried to subscribe to the KeyDown and KeyPress events hoping that the event would fire for as long as the key was being pressed but it doesn't work.

Comment: You have no effective control over the keyboard controller's repeat feature.  The snippet is very unhelpful, but a typical scenario is WASD control in a game.  Doesn't work when the player presses more than one key, the second key press cancels the repeat of the first, even though it is still down.  Must be fixed by relying on KeyDown+KeyUp that merely updates a status variable and a game loop that uses it, repeating as necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant can you please write an answer with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue by using the PreviewKeyDown event. It keeps firing while a key is being pressed, unlike the KeyDown and KeyPress events.

Answer (score 0):

Set some state variable in KeyDown to true, then subscribe to KeyUp event and set it to false.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer keyTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
...
keyTimer.Tick += new EventHadler(KeyPressedHandler);
...

private void canvas_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void canvas_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyTimer.Enabled = false;
}

private static void KeyPressedHandler(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
  //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this will work. Are you suggesting that I should do all my work inside the KeyDown event? I want the KeyDown event to fire continually while the keyboard key is being held down. I don't see how these variables will make that happen. Can you please clarify?

Comment: If you want to continiously fire a function, then you can create a timer in KeyDown and dispose it in keyUp. Then implement your logic in timer handler.

Comment: I couldn't get your last suggestion working. It seems that the timer doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Is it some kind of a game that has a loop, or you just want to start doing something while a key pressed?

Comment: I'm writing a vector graphics editor. I need to move the drawn rectangle when the key is being pressed. That means that while I hold my Up arrow down, the shape needs to keep moving. But regardless of what I'm doing, it could be any code at all that should be able to run while the key is being pressed.

Comment: Edited my answer to show the general idea. Of course you don't have to create timer for every key - you can use some dictionary of key states.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. While you were doing that I resolved the issue by using the PreviewKeyDown event instead. This event keeps firing while a key is being held down.